# Erro ao converter JSON

Tags: c#

Ao converter meus dados recebo o seguinte erro:

> Input string '42.0' is not a valid integer

Esse erro acontece pois eu recebo um valor `string` "42.0" em um campo `int` -> `Con_codigo`

Como posso resolver??

Meu codigo:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(UrlApi2))
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string resul = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    ListaContatos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ContatosViewModel>>(resul);
}
```

Meu Json:

```
[
  {
    "Con_tpcadastro": "BAN",
    "Con_codigo": 42.0,
    "Con_nome": "ASD",
    "Con_vinculo": "SAD",
    "Con_fone": "ASD",
    "Con_fax": "ASD",
    "Con_celular": "ASDAS",
    "Con_email": "DAS"
  },
  {
    "Con_tpcadastro": "BAN",
    "Con_codigo": 42.0,
    "Con_nome": "FDS",
    "Con_vinculo": "SDF",
    "Con_fone": "FSD",
    "Con_fax": "FSD",
    "Con_celular": "FSD",
    "Con_email": "SDF"
  }
]
```

ContatosViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SoftluxWebCore.ViewModels.Tabelas.Financeiro
{
public class ContatosViewModel
{
    public string Con_tpcadastro { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    public int? Con_codigo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Informe o Nome do Contato")]
    public string Con_nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vinculo")]
    public string Con_vinculo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fone")]
    public string Con_fone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "FAX")]
    public string Con_fax { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Celular")]
    public string Con_celular { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Con_email { get; set; }

}
```

}

Comment: Ou você desserializa o arquivo (ou apenas a propriedade, se for possível) por conta própria e faz o tratamento para não considerar números com ponto como decimais. Ou você o desserializa para uma propriedade decimal e depois faz o tratamento e converte para inteiro. A segunda opção me parece bem mais fácil.

Comment: Note que o valor da propriedade `Con_codigo` no JSON **não é uma string**. É um número decimal.

Comment: Pelo erro, dizia Input string '42.0', achei que estivesse considerando como uma string, obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff, acredito que a classe a qual pertence o seu objeto *"ListaContatos"* possua uma propriedade de nome *"Con_codigo"*. Essa propriedade precisa ser to tipo ***decimal*** para receber esse tipo de valor.

Comment: Ela é do tipo int, vou editar publicação

Comment: Porém, esta recebendo como se fosse string "42.0" e deveria receber apenas "42"

Comment: @JeffHenrique No JSON não é uma string, é um decimal.

Comment: Entendo, você tem certeza de que não seria o envio desse dado que já estaria dessa forma antes de chegar em sua aplicação?

Comment: Ah sim, então tenho que fazer um tratamento, vou buscar ver como faz

Comment: @JeffHenrique Você já verificou no serviço que fornece o json `await httpClient.GetAsync(UrlApi2))` provavelmente ele manda um decimal, pois se o mesmo estivesse mandando inteiro mandaria apenas 42

Comment: @JeffHenrique, o problema não é o seu View Model e sim o que a API retorna

Comment: @JulioBorges vc está certo, na api o valor é double, e no meu projeto é int, vou alterar, achei que fosse erro ao converter o json, obrigado

Comment: @JeffHenrique, blz, aceite a resposta do Sérgio Lopes, pois ele estava correto

Comment: Irei aceitar, só estou testando para ver se vai funcionar

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado SérgioLopes, @JulioBorges e Linq

Comment: Foi um prazer ajudar!